# Testing an Activitys WebView using Robolectric, not loading page

Tags: android, android-webview, robolectric, android-testing, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to test out some content in a `WebView` using Robolectric, however there is no data coming into it.

I have called the following before `loadUrl()` on the `WebView`.

```
Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer().interceptHttpRequests(false);
Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer().interceptResponseContent(true);
```

And I have also called the following in order to try and flush whatever is queued up in Robolectric-land.  I do have to do this in order for me to get a few other things to kick through.

```
Robolectric.runBackgroundTasks();
Robolectric.runUiThreadTasks();
Robolectric.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks();
```

Here is the code that loads the url

```
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);

    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webView.setInitialScale(1);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
           super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

           Log.d(TAG, newProgress + " URL: " + view.getUrl());//this never happens!
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("https://the-url.to/load");

    Log.d(TAG, "Loading: " + url);//i see this..
```

I really like Robolectric and how it solves the emulator overhead problems, but I need it to work with the WebView implementation above.  Any ideas?

Comment: hyyyy plz help me about how to test web view through robolectric i am not able to finding any code form google.

Answer (score 2):

What will you test? Maybe it's enough to check, that the loadurl was called with expected url.

looks like more is not possible current.
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/8c85d5ba50b1e06fd2918d48ad6c6487e8340750/robolectric/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowWebView.java

Comment: I was hoping to inject click events on DOM elements, and then validate the behavior.

Comment: Perhaps can you use an extra tool for testing web view content. I'm not so familiar with web test but found http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net